# Getting unsupported_grant_type when exchanging code for a token

Tags: json, vba, http

Using VBA, I am able to authenticate the user and obtain 'code' successfully using my sandbox account. However, when I attempt to exchange the permission token for an access token, I get status code 400, Bad Request (unsupported_grant_type). I searched for similar problems and tried many suggestions to no avail. I have been successful in using the implicit grant process, but would like to now switch to code grant. I validated the Base64 conversion using an online tool. It worked fine. The process looks very simple and straight forward. Any help is much appreciated.

The VBA code I'm using follows:

```
strURL = "https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token"

strAuthorization = Base64EncodeString(gstrIntegrationKey & ":" & gstrSecretKey)

Set objJSON = New Dictionary
objJSON.Add "grant_type", "authorization_code"
objJSON.Add "code", strCode
strJSON = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(objJSON)

Set objHTTP = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

objHTTP.Open "POST", strURL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type: ", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Accept: ", "application/json"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization: ", "Basic " & strAuthorization
objHTTP.send strJSON

Do Until objHTTP.ReadyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

strResponse = Replace(objHTTP.responseText, "null", """null""")

If objHTTP.Status <> 200 Then
    If Not DocuSignErr(strResponse, objHTTP.Status, objHTTP.statusText) Then Stop
    GoTo FailedExit
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The body should be form URL encoded not JSON encoded. Instead of using the `Dictionary` and running it through `JsonConverter.ConvertToJson`, you should encode it in as a form (e.g., `value1=a&value2=b`). So, you can do something like this:

```
strURL = "https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token"

strAuthorization = Base64EncodeString(gstrIntegrationKey & ":" & gstrSecretKey)

Set objHTTP = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

objHTTP.Open "POST", strURL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type: ", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Accept: ", "application/json"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization: ", "Basic " & strAuthorization
objHTTP.send "grant_type=authorization_code&code=" & strCode

...
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I made the change and now I get another Status Code 400 “unauthorized client”. I am the DS Admin.

Comment: Make sure the client can perform the code flow. You said implicit works, maybe there's some setting in DS that controls what flows the client can perform. (I didn't see one in the docs.) Also, it looks like `redirect_uri` is required for DS (in the authorization request). I'd send it in the token request as well.

Comment: Did that help @Ken? Any more clues?

Comment: Hi Travis, Implicit grant worked in production for awhile. Then I tried to switch to code grant when I received the above errors. Now implicit grant stopped working. I tried to research the problem, but nothing works. Everything in the sandbox account works fine. In production with implicit, I’m able the authenticate the user, get the user profile, but when I attempt to download envelopes, I get “user does not belong to specified account”.

Comment: Sounds like a different question in that case?